# What to include to use jQuery UI Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

I was looking at the scripts included with WP and dont see what I can include to use jQuery UI Auto Complete. What do I use? I tried including the whole jQuery UI from Google CDN and auto complete works but some parts of the admin dashboard fails. eg. Custom Menus

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses the [jQuery Suggest](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/suggest) plugin, which existed before Autocomplete was added to UI. You can enqueue 'suggest' to load it if it'll work for your needs.

Otherwise I think you'd have to build a custom jQuery UI download and then just extract the Autocomplete code, otherwise you'll have two versions of things stepping on each other and you'll get the failure you describe.

Comment: What version of jQuery/UI does WP use? Also Auto Complete uses Widget & Position what WP Scripts do I need?

Comment: look in `wp-includes/js/jquery/`. looks like UI version is 1.8.12. I see `ui.widget.js` and `ui.position.js` files, try enqueueing `'jquery-ui-position'` and `'jquery-ui-widget'` along with `'jquery-ui-core'`.